# Save Gmail attachment to different Gdrive

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-drive, attachments

I have a personal Gmail (Google) account created some years back for my Android phone. Recently I have been given access to a new Gmail account by my employer.

When I open the Gmail or Gdrive apps they both show the two accounts and allow me to easily switch between them (Gmail has a useful combined *All inboxes* option too). So far, so good.

However if I open a mail sent by my employer to my work Gmail account and click on the *Save to Drive* icon on the attached PDF, the pop-up dialog box allows me to save the attachment only to my personal Gdrive account; it doesn't list my work Gdrive account at all.

So how do I directly save an attachment from my work Gmail to my work Gdrive?

[Save to Drive dialog in Gmail for attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27J5X.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Directly you can't. What you need to do is:

- Tap on the file, and open the pdf file with the Drive.
- When it opens, click on the Drive icon (the icon with a plus).
- Select the account to saved it to, press Ok.

Not sure if this process is acceptable to you as it is equivalent of downloading and then uploading the file to the preferred account.

[image: IMG:]